# For loops slowing down python

Tags: python

I'm trying to run

```
f = open("FurElise.mp3", "rb")
for x in f.read():
    print x
```

Trying to read each character in a test mp3 file. However, I noticed that using this method takes way longer than just `print(f.read())`. Using `print(f.read())` will output the whole file in ~10 seconds, but using the method above can take several minutes. Does anyone know why this is, or if there's a faster way to loop through the file character by character?

Comment: What do you actually get from printing the contents of an mp3?

Comment: Part of the problem is you are writing twice as many characters; the `print` statement adds an implicit newline character after every `x`.

Comment: +chepner so is there any way to loop through a file character by character, without it taking so long? +roganjosh Strange non-english characters, same as what you get if you open an MP3 in notepad++

Comment: @Hugh printing to `stdout` is _very_ slow. To my imagination, `print` cannot serve some reasonable purpose here, but it's not really down to the `for` loop itself - more about `print` I would say.

Comment: _"so is there any way to loop through a file character by character, without it taking so long?"_ Yes. Loop through the characters without printing them.

Comment: A huge portion of the time is taken up by **scrolling** since you're printing each character on a separate line in the one case.

Comment: @Hugh, if you just want to see the file's byte content, try `print repr(x),` *with* the comma, might be closer to what you're expecting

Comment: This isn't really a programming problem. If your goal is to examine the contents of an MP3 file, just use `hexdump` to write the output in a suitably readable form to a text file, and use your favorite editor or pager to examine the contents at your leisure.

Comment: +davedwards I need it as a string, though. I currently have it being placed into an array, then converting the array to a string

Comment: Then save it into a string: `with open(...) as f: data = f.read()`

Comment: +Norrius Apologies, I should have been more clear, I have to perform a math calculation on ord(x) for every character, then store my new results in the file

Comment: Then do it? The loop isn't slow, `print` is. Also, use `@username` to ping people (plus does nothing).

Comment: @Hugh, did you get it working? you can build the bytes into a string, before the `for`-loop: `s=''`, then inside the `for`-loop: `s+=repr(ord(x))`, then outside the `for`-loop, `print s` should be a `<str>` type, that looks something like `255251144108015240000000000 ...`

Answer (score 1):

Python has to do a lot more with your loop, as it first needs to setup everything for it, after calling f.read() and storing it somewhere in memory. It then needs to call the print() function for each byte of your file, when the loop-less way, it calls it once. Calling a function isn't magic, python creates a stack frame for it (it allocates some memory for its variables), and then executes it. Again, the print function does stuff to print your object. It probably calls other functions to format the argument, etc...
Because all this work is done for each single byte, instead of once, it of course needs way more time.